# How to cancel my own Wiki edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

After editing a Wiki tag, I understood that I made an error and the modification was not relevant (It was already in another tag). How to cancel it, so it not reviewed and rejected ?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/633864/coil?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cancel suggested edits. Not on regular posts, and not on tag wikis.

Your edit will either be approved or declined in due course (it has been for your [most recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11128622)).

Comment: Yes, it's for the most recent edit. Humm the edit was approved and shouldn't have. How to roll back now ?

Comment: Want me to roll back the edit?

Comment: Yes please because it was approved.

Comment: Done; the change is gone.